# HTML/jQuery Save order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, draggable

I'm using the jquery plugin called shapeshift. It's like jqueryui sortable but with better animations. The divs can be dragged and dropped. But I can't seem to figure out how to save their order so that on browser refesh the order remains the same where I left them.

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Shikhar_Srivastava/aC367/

```
 $(".container").shapeshift({minColumns: 3});
```

I'm initiating the plugin as above.

Please help me on my fiddle.
Thanks.

Comment: Is there an event that fires after you move some around?

Comment: just try to save your div's position in localstorage and retrieve those values on page refresh..

Comment: @Goku Yes, there is. It's  $containers.on "ss-drop-complete".

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla Please try to help me on the fiddle. I'm banging my head since yesterday. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one container

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKQBA/3/)

```
var $con=$(".container").shapeshift({
    minColumns: 3
});

function getPos(id){
   var p=localStorage[id]; 
    var ro={left:100000,top:-1,unknown:true};
    if(p!==undefined) ro=JSON.parse(p);
    //alert('get Pos:'+id+' '+JSON.stringify(ro));
    return ro;
}
function setPos(id,p){
    //alert('set Pos:'+id+' '+JSON.stringify(p));
   localStorage[id]=JSON.stringify(p); 
}
function arrange(){
    var o={};
    var con=$(".container:nth-child(1)");
    var els=$(".container:nth-child(1) div");
    els.each(function(x){
        var me=$(this);
        var id=me.attr('id');
        var o_=o[id]={};
        o_.id=me.attr('id');
        o_.p=getPos(id);
    });
    for(var i in o){
        var oo=o[i];
        var el=$('#'+oo.id);
        if(!oo.unknown){
          el.css('left',''+oo.p.left+'px');
        }
    }
}
function savePs(){
    var els=$(".container:nth-child(1) div");
    els.each(function(){
        var me=$(this);
        setPos(me.attr('id'),me.position());
    });    
}
var $con=$(".container:nth-child(1)");
$con.on('ss-rearranged',function(e,selected){
    var id=$(selected);
    setTimeout(function(){
        //var me=$(selected);
        savePs();
        //setPos(me.attr('id'),me.position());
    },500);
});
arrange();
//savePs();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKQBA/3/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Robin. It works but alas it is only for one container. Nonetheless appreciate your effort.

Comment: I have the utmost confidence in your abilities to figure out the two iterator functions that are needed to cover those bases :)

Comment: Ah..I'm fairly new to javascript and I started to learn localstorage just yesterday. I didn't get what you're trying to say there. Now I look like a fool. Anyways if you can somehow help me in my fiddle and make it compatible for more than one containers I'll upvote/choose your answer as my answer.

Comment: Hey! Your code works but there is some glitch. when there is change in order it is saved. But when the browser is refreshed the divs overlap each other or are not in their position (grid). What's going on?

Comment: Ah..nevermind I fixed it. You just forgot to add/attach .on('ss-drop-complete',saver) to the container. Thanks once again.

Comment: @user3716080 Yes, I noticed some glitchiness, but I think it was not the one you are talking about, it was on doing a small drag the div would get stuck out of position. If you find the right event, you could probably get rid of the timeout and reduce the number of event tie-ins. ss-drop-complete may be the only one you need.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a cookie. So I would first include the jQuery Cookie script (found here: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/src/jquery.cookie.js), then create the cookies (one for each each `.container`) each time an element is moved:

```
/* save cookie */
$('.container').on("ss-drop-complete", function() {
    var containerCookieCounter = 0;
    $('.container').each(function() {

        /* cookie = 12h */
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (720 * 60 * 1000));
        $.cookie('savepositions' + containerCookieCounter, $(this).html(), { expires: date, path: '/' });
        containerCookieCounter += 1;
    });
});
```

Then, before initiating the shapeshift-function, check if there are existing cookies:

```
/* cookies... */
if ($.cookie('savepositions0')) {
    var containerCounter = 0;
    $('.container').each(function() {
        $(this).html($.cookie('savepositions' + containerCounter));
        containerCounter += 1;
    });
}
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/FvUcQ/

Answer (score 0):

As commenters have suggested, you need to use `localStorage` to store and retrieve the state, and save that state after the `ss-drop-complete` event.

Here is the entire JS I used in this [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qXDZ/):

```
$(function () {
    // retrieve from localStorage if there is a saved state
    var saved = localStorage.getItem('arrangement');
    if (saved) {
        populateArrangement($('.container').parent(), JSON.parse(saved));
    }

    $(".container").shapeshift({
        minColumns: 3
    }).on('ss-drop-complete', function () {
        // get the new arrangement and serialise it to localStorage as a string
        var rows = getArrangement();
        localStorage.setItem('arrangement', JSON.stringify(rows));
    });

    // return the data needed to reconstruct the collections as an array of arrays
    function getArrangement() {
        var rows = [];
        $('.container').each(function () {
            var elementsInRow = [];
            $(this).find('.ss-active-child').each(function () {
                elementsInRow.push({
                    value: parseInt($(this).text(), 10),
                    colspan: $(this).data('ss-colspan') || 1
                });
            });
            rows.push(elementsInRow);
        });
        return rows;
    }

    // use the arrangement to populate the DOM correctly
    function populateArrangement(container, newArrangement) {
        $(container).find('.container').remove();
        $.each(newArrangement, function (index, row) {
            var $container = $('<div class="container"></div>');
            $container.appendTo(container);
            $.each(row, function (index, element) {
                var $div = $('<div></div>');
                $div.text(element.value);
                if (element.colspan > 1) 
                    $div.attr('data-ss-colspan', element.colspan);
                $container.append($div);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: That doesnt save the order, does it?

Comment: @MarkRobbins Why don't you just click on the Fiddle-link to see whether it works instead of asking if it works? (Works beautifully in my browser by the way.)

Comment: @Niffler Because I can generally read the code and tell he is not really meeting the requirements here. So its a rhetorical question. Sure it APPEARS to save the order, but its just recreating divs. Put images in those divs or html and his 'solution' breaks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some sort of server side code you can add the order to a hidden field on the ss-drop-complete function and then post this back to the server on post back.  You can then just re-output the values back when the page re-renders and you can use this information in any server side code you need.

I've done something similar when working with jquery mobile and ASP.NET to save back to a database the order.

If not, the local storage option could be a good way to go.